# compiling an open-source iphone app

Tags: xcode, ios, compilation

I want to compile an open source iPhone app(https://github.com/newsyc/newsyc/) but since I don't have a Mac, I can't do it using Xcode. Is there any other way to do this? Is there anything on the Cydia appstore that might help?(I already have jailbroken my iPod)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sorry but the only way to compile iOs-apps is XCode. the gcc compiler does support objective-c, but the framwork-technique is only supported by apple's compiler and the newest apple compiler only runs on intel-based Macs.

There are ways to [make apps with Windows-SDKs](http://maniacdev.com/2010/01/iphone-development-windows-options-available/) which give you limited, but sometimes satisfying, functionality. But since you already have objective-c source code, you'll need a mac (or a friend with a mac) to compile it.

I know that some people managed to run Mac OS X in a virtual machine on windows which could be your last solution - you'll have to google this a lot because it can be really tricky. Maybe finding someone willing to compile the sources for you will be a lot faster xD